# R fread importation return 0 lines

Tags: r, csv, fread

I'm having trouble understanding what's is wrong in my fread importation.
When I use read.csv with the same parameter the data is reading properly but I can't use it since other file don't work on it.

```
    ths<-read.csv(path_data, sep = ",",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    df <- data.table::fread(file=path_data,
        header = TRUE,
        sep = ",",quote = '',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I can't give you the file so here is a data sample:

```
> "hal-02409822,1,https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02409822,ART,10.1063/1.5127050,,Plasma
> diagnostic tools for ECR ion sources—What can we learn from these
> experiments for the next generation sources,,""O. Tarvainen,T.
> Kalvas,H. Koivisto,R. Kronholm,M. Marttinen,M. Sakildien,V.
> Toivanen,I. Izotov,V. Skalyga,J.
> Angot"",2019,2019,""0.phys,1.phys.phys,2.phys.phys.phys-acc-ph,0.phys"",Rev.Sci.Instrum.,,90,,113321,,,,,,""phys,phys"",,phys.phys.phys-acc-ph,en,false"
> "hal-02277876,1,https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02277876,ART,10.1103/PhysRevE.100.013205,,Physics
> of relativistic collisionless shocks: The scattering-center
> frame,,""Guy Pelletier,Laurent Gremillet,Arno Vanthieghem,Martin
> Lemoine"",2019,2019,""0.phys,1.phys.astr,0.phys,1.phys.phys,2.phys.phys.phys-gen-ph"",""Physical
> Review E : Statistical, Nonlinear, and Soft Matter Physics"",American
> Physical Society,100,,013205,,,,,Plasma Physics,""phys,phys"",Plasma
> Physics,phys.astr,en,false"
```

Comment: Since you are using `header = TRUE` your files provides a header row. Afaik every row needs as many columns (seperated by `,`) as your header. Looking at your data sample, I doubt this is fulfilled.

Comment: @MartinGal Thanks for your time,  I thought of that too, and you're right there is more "," in line than in header but event with header=FALSE fread doesn't work whereas read csv seems to adapt. Why is that ? is there parameter i can give to correct fread?

Comment: I think every row needs the same amount of `,`. Perhaps you could try with a small example (two rows)? Looking at your data sample I don't think that file is well formated. This looks like a row was split into multiple rows.

Comment: in fact there are only to rwo but the post dont allow me to put it il same line sorry,
if you cut at the ""hal-0.." and bring in the same row you will have the line (i'm i clear enought ?)